# Comparing performance of Quasi-binomial model and Beta-binomial model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, biostatistics, beta-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I read some books in biostatistics about fitting binary date with Beta-Binomial regression model and Quasi-Binomial regression model. It proposes a setting:

**Setting:**
Assuming we have a sequence of binomial trials of size $N_i$. $Y_i$ is the number of events of interest, $x_i$ is a predictor associated with trial $i$, and $\pi_i$ is the proportion of the events of interest ($i = 1,2,...,n$). Books mentioned that it is very likely that data in reality doesn't have binomial variance so we have to use models that adjusted **Overdispersion**. And therefore we can consider two models:

1. **Beta-Binomial regression model with an overdispersion parameter:**
   $$
   P_i|\pi, \tau_i^2 \sim Beta(a_i, b_i), \quad \text{where} \quad \pi_i = \frac{a_i}{a_i + b_i} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_i^{2} = \frac{1}{a_i + b_i + 1}
   $$
   $$
   Y_i|P_i \sim Binomial(N_i, P_i)
   $$
   $$
   \pi_i = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i}}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i}}}, \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1,2,...,n
   $$
   In here, $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^{2}$ are fixed constants for each observation rather than random variables.
2. **Quasi-Binomial regression model:**
   We need to assume a mean-covariance structure for quasi-likelihood function.
   $$
   E(Y_i) = N_i \pi_i \quad \text{and} \quad Var(Y_i) = N_i\pi_i(1-\pi_i)\alpha
   $$
   $$
   log(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_1}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i, \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1,2,...,n
   $$

**Question:**
I noticed that I can use the Pearson residual
$$
R_i = \frac{y_i - N_i\hat{\pi}_i}{\sqrt{N_i\hat{\pi}_i(1-\hat{\pi}_i)}}
$$
to compare performance of two models. **But I don't know how I can build up the connection between the Pearson residual with the models' variances. I am wondering does anyone know how the Pearson residual related with models?**

**Attempt:**
For **Beta-Binomial regression model**, I find that the variance of the $Y_i$ can be obtained by the law of total variance
$$
Var(Y_i) = Var[E(Y_i|P_i)] + E[Var(Y_i|P_i)] = [\tau_i^2(N_i - 1)+1]N_i\pi_i(1-\pi_i).
$$
**But how can I obtain the $\hat{\pi}_i$ under this model.**

For the **Quasi-Binomial regression model**, **how can I see the connection among $\hat{\pi}_i$, the variance of model, and $R_i$?**

Comment: Noticed that when $\tau_i^2 \to 0$, $Var(Y_i) \to N_i\pi_i(1-\pi_i)$ which is the binomial variance, the denominator in $R_i$ is just the squared root of a binomial variance.